# Why does this function have exponential complexity big O instead of quadratic?

Tags: python, big-o

The following function has been given:

```
def genSubsets(L):
    res = []
    if len(L) == 0:
        return [[]]
    smaller = genSubsets(L[:-1])
    extra = L[-1:]
    new = []
    for small in smaller:
        new.append(small+extra)
    return smaller+new
```

From my understanding, i making a copy of a list is (O n), then looping is (O n) as well. Which should make this (O n^2). However, it seems that my logic is flawed and the answer is (O 2^n). Why?

Comment: There are 2^n subsets of a set. If you're producing 2^n distinct lists as part of your function, you can't possibly do that in faster than `Θ(2^n)`.

Answer (score 2):

> From my understanding, i making a copy of a list is (O n)

You are correct that making a copy of a list of n items takes time O(n). And in this case, each of the lists that's being copied is a subset of the original list, which has length n, so each list copied does take time O(n).

> then looping is (O n) as well

Looping over a list of length n takes time O(n). However, in this case, the lists that you're looping over do *not* have n elements in them. There are 2<sup>n</sup> subsets of a set of size n, so at the top-level recursive call, when you recursively generate all subsets of `L[:-1]`, you will end up with a list of 2<sup>n-1</sup> items. Looping over that list takes time O(2<sup>n</sup>).

More generally, when looking at a loop or a list, it's important to ask "how many times does this loop run?" or "how many elements are in this list?"